# WCF windows service not connect to database

Tags: .net, mysql, wcf

I have created WCF dll and succesfully tested using WCFTestCLient in Visual Studio.
problem exist after i hosted the WCF i just created in Windows Services.

the error said :
"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)"

are there some configuration i miss, cause i already copied app.config from the WCF Project to Windows Services Project.

I'm using C# .NET 4 and MySQL on Windows 7 Machine

thanks.

Comment: How did you install the Windows Service?

Comment: I installed it using installutil.exe

Comment: It could be permissions issue. Post your connection string. What identity is the service running as?

Comment: Is the service running on the same machine as the database?

Comment: @sliverninja this is my connection string  
-------  
connectionString="server=localhost;User Id=***;password=***;Persist Security Info=True;database=***;port=3308"
      providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />  
-------  
   
i put this in my windows service app  
-------  
processInstaller.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;  
-------  
so i believe it runs as Local System

Comment: @tim yes, the service is running in the same server as the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my mistakes,
before, i only copied connection string part and service model part from WCF library config file to Windows Service Project config file because that what i learned online.

i forgot that i'm using different membership provider than the samples online, in this case i use MySQL membership provider, so i have to copied membership, profile and role manager part also.

after i done that, my windows service work as i expected.

thank to all the answer, it help me to recheck my configuration file.

hope this can help someone else too....